# How to get started with Compass/Sass on Mac – Invalid CSS error?

Tags: css, macos, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to get started with Compass/Sass on my Mac. After running `sudo gem install compass`, I have set up a project with a single `main.scss` file and I use `compass watch` to have the file automatically compiled to CSS.

`main.scss` looks like this:

```
@import "compass/css3/border-radius"

div .blah .baz {
  @include border-radius(4px, 4px);
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Seems like nothing complicated, right? Well, every time I save the file, I get an error like this:

```
>>> Change detected to: /Users/mikl/Sites/ddk7/profiles/blaahval/themes/kaskelot/./scss/main.scss
    error ./scss/main.scss (Line 3: Invalid CSS after ".../border-radius"": expected selector or at-rule, was "$blue: #3bbfce;")
overwrite ./css/main.css
```

Is there something wrong with my SCSS syntax, or just compass just have very poor error messages?

Comment: not familiar with Compass, but.. missing semicolon at the end of line 1?

Comment: have you tried declaring the `border-radius` mixin directly in main.scss to rule out the `@import` misbehaviour?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @jnpcl said, a semi-colon would be good. However, if that was the issue it should throw an error directly related to that.

This seems like a stretch, but did you copy and paste that line? Perhaps there is character weirdness happening?

Comment: As it turns out, it was in fact the missing semicolon that did it, Sass just has rather poor error messages.

Comment: Thank you. The missing semicolon was the issue. @import "bootstrap"; was required for me.